# hyperledger fabric : Could not find matching private key for SKI

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

It's my first post on stackoverflow, normaly i found solution everytime i come to stackoverflow, but not this time :(

I'm trying to implement a hyperledger fabric solution for a supply chain. 
i can execute channel, chaincode, addpeers... i can also instantiate and invoke chaincode by terminal.

I want to create an app with node sdk that interact with my blockchain, so i want to use fabric-ca. Below is my docker-compose-base.yaml file:

```
ca_acheteur.example.com:
 image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
 environment:
   - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
   - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca_acheteur.example.com                               
   - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.acheteur.example.com-cert.pem
   - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/abef4d982d505c588c15bf25af3270f403c94daff71301e37a9c84abe41e6c71_sk
 ports:
   - "7054:7054"
 command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
 volumes:
   - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
 container_name: ca_acheteur.example.com
 networks:
   - basic
ca_vendeur.example.com:
 image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
 environment:
   - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
   - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca_vendeur.example.com
   - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.vendeur.example.com-cert.pem
   - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/42ecb9a24235f691c5392d7eecebc458827b00bf0bf150fd727298b321b6d51d_sk
 ports:
   - "8054:8054"
 command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
 volumes:
   - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/vendeur.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
 container_name: ca_vendeur.example.com
 networks:
   - basic
```

When i start containers i get this results :

```
Creating ca_acheteur.example.com           ... done
Creating peer0.acheteur.example.com        ... done
Creating peer0.vendeur.example.com         ... done
Creating ca_vendeur.example.com            ... done
Creating orderer.example.com               ... done
Creating couchdb                           ... done
Creating cli                               ... done
```

The CA container fails and below is docker log:

```
2018/06/19 17:10:01 [INFO] Created default configuration file at /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
2018/06/19 17:10:01 [INFO] Starting server in home directory: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
2018/06/19 17:10:01 [INFO] Server Version: 1.1.0
2018/06/19 17:10:01 [INFO] Server Levels: &{Identity:1 Affiliation:1 Certificate:1}
Error: Failed to find private key for certificate in '/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.vendeur.example.com-cert.pem': Could not find matching private key for SKI: Failed getting key for SKI [[159 75 128 227 121 9 61 98 235 18 118 191 43 69 158 184 170 52 121 51 27 147 132 228 64 195 35 218 6 9 158 30]]: Key with SKI 9f4b80e379093d62eb1276bf2b459eb8aa3479331b9384e440c323da06099e1e not found in /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/msp/keystore
```

The FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE is the same as my local ca on peers.

Let me know what am I missing here.

Answer (score 5):

It an issue of ca's private key.
After you executing generate.sh script new cert are generated. Hence you will have to update the docker-compose.yml file.

Paste the file name from path--> crypto-*config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/_____-sk*

in docker-compose.yml file---->

environment

**- FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/___-sk**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error as op but with only one ca server.

The only fix I found was to edit FABRIC_CA_SERVER_KEYFILE environment variable to match the name of the private key after generating it.

Edit: After searching how it was configured in the fabric samples, I saw that they named it CA2_PRIVATE_KEY in the ca configuration in docker-compose-e2e.yaml.

It is automatically renamed after generating it in https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/first-network/byfn.sh  line 271-281.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. I don't know what OS you are using, but I had this problem on Windows. The Fabric docs specify: `If you are using Docker Toolbox on Windows 7 or macOS, you will need to use a location under C:\Users (Windows 7) or /Users (macOS) when installing and running the samples.`

When I moved my project to a user folder it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the suggest "to edit FABRIC_CA_SERVER_KEYFILE environment variable to match the name of the private key after generating it". And it's Working!!!!!

My error:

```
Error: Failed to find private key for certificate in '/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem': Could not find matching private key for SKI: Failed getting key for SKI [[......]: Key with SKI 300dbdb3ba348ba85045c40fa3f6985cc1c9f9e9fc5dcd21fd43b1faabbe052b not found in /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/msp/keystore
```

I change it for the result of script generate.sh in the path of my application:

```
basic-network\crypto-config\peerOrganizations\org1.example.com\ca\e389cdd4b312bf2c8873577ed7afdbd65f061e5546ed25e41f3935324c7a159e_sk
```

And it's working!!! My node fabric-ca it's up!