# CA stack service failed to start

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm having this error while deploying stack of CA.

> Error: Failed to find private key for certificate in
>   '/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem':
>   Could not find matching private key for SKI: Failed getting key for
>   SKI [[21 208 34 108 92 98 114 142 23 136 0 189 188 55 155 135 23 90
>   147 173 157 62 155 19 173 212 128 3 175 212 121 41]]: Key with SKI
>   15d0226c5c62728e178800bdbc379b87175a93ad9d3e9b13add48003afd47929 not
>   found in /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/msp/keystore

I have made sure that key is same as "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca" in yml file. But still its throwing error.. Any idea about this?

Comment: what is the command sequence / activity that yielded the message? Not enough info here

Comment: 1. I started docker swarm

Comment: 1. I started docker swarm. 2. I created overlay network. 3. I deployed stack service for peers, couchdb, orderer, ca. Stack service for peers, couchdb and orderer is getting created successfully but its throwing error for CA as shown above. So I verified the key with "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca". So not getting why its throwing error. I have configured network referring this article.. https://medium.com/coinmonks/hyperledger-composer-docker-swarm-a15bef803c8b  .. Not getting what I'm missing.

Comment: We would need to see your config in order to help with this.  fabric-ca is not finding the matching key for the public cert

Comment: https://medium.com/coinmonks/hyperledger-composer-docker-swarm-a15bef803c8b Using this I have developed the fabric network. I have mounted NFS. Im working on docker swarm. I have used service endpoint mode as dns. My fabric network configuration contains 2 peers, 1 orderer, 1 ca and 2 couchdb instances. Im placing and generating crypto artifacts in /etc/srv/NFS directory. And after that Im creating overlay network. And starting services of CA, orderer, Peers and couchdb. Please let me know if you want any information other than this.. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hyperledger fabric : Could not find matching private key for SKI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933982/hyperledger-fabric-could-not-find-matching-private-key-for-ski)

Answer (score 0):

Within the docker run command, are you placing the secret key inside curly brackets such as this?

FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/{15d0226c5c62728e178800bdbc379b87175a93ad9d3e9b13add48003afd47929}

If so, the cause of your error is that this isn't the correct path. Remove the brackets to make the path complete.