# Finding private key and certificate fails for FABRIC-CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I was able to successfully run through "[Build Your First Network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html)" tutorial. Next, I've started following the tutorial "[Write Your First Application](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/write_first_app.html)". I'm using release 1.1. Here, when I'm issuing the `./startFabric.sh node` command, it is able to spin up all the docker containers except the FABRIC_CA.

On checking the logs I found that it is not able to find the matching private for the certificate specified. To give it a try, I regenerated the certificates, genesis block and channel transaction again. I specified these newly generated certificate file and the key file in the services section for CA in the "docker-compose.yml" file.

Steps that I've followed till now:

1. Killed the stale/active containers using: `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)`
2. Cleared the cached network using: `docker network prune`.
3. Installed the node packages.
4. Supplied the command: `startFabric.sh node`.
5. Name of my CA container is "ca.example.com". So tried streaming the CA logs using: `docker logs -f ca.example.com`

The last step spits out the following error:

> Error: Failed to find private key for certificate in
>   '/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem':
>   Could not find matching private key for SKI: Failed getting key for
>   SKI [[121 3 161 188 208 43 162 82 194 238 60 39 201 202 175 48 142 53
>   142 226 34 112 214 8 95 124 86 11 87 93 41 229]]: Key with SKI
>   7903a1bcd02ba252c2ee3c27c9caaf308e358ee22270d6085f7c560b575d29e5 not
>   found in /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/msp/keystore

Am I missing out on any step?

P.S. Similar question is asked a few days ago but remains unanswered due to lack of information. Link: [CA stack service failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51532609/ca-stack-service-failed-to-start).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hyperledger fabric : Could not find matching private key for SKI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933982/hyperledger-fabric-could-not-find-matching-private-key-for-ski)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem` cannot correctly mounted on Fabric-ca container. Two recommend that you should try to fix it.

1. carefully check the docker-compose.yaml file that you mentioned above about ca volumes and environments configuration. Trace the source path of the ca key if you can.
2. Remember to replace the FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE parameter at `env` and `command` in yaml if you regenerate the certification.

Answer (score 0):

remove `fabric-samples` and clone from `https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples` works for me